# Python 2.7, Requests library, can't get unicode

Tags: python, parsing, unicode, python-requests

Documentation for Request library says that requests.get() method returns unicode always. But when I try to know what an encoding was returned, I see "windows-1251". That's a problem. When I try to get requests.get(url).text, there's an error, because current url's content has a Cyrillic symbols.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.weblancer.net/jobs/'
r = requests.get(url)
print r.encoding
print r.text
```

I got something like that:

```
windows-1251
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 256-263: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is it a problem of Python 2.7 or there is not a problem at all ?
Help me

Comment: Use `.content` not `.text`, also where are you running it from?#

Comment: I believe it's `print` problem. Python need to convert text to ascii to print it in terminal, but it's imposible

Comment: I run it from Sublime Text with anaconda
Yes, I've tried to run this code from console, and r.text returned html. But r.encoding still returns "windows-1251".
But type(r.text) returns "unicode"
It makes me crazy

Comment: When I run the above code, I get all the text.  I don't get the error you mention.

Comment: Can you provide the *full* error message, so we can confirm it's coming from where you think it's coming from?

Comment: @GreenAsJade, it is coming from `print r.text` which is trying to decode as ascii hence the error

Comment: @GreenAsJade, read the output,  *windows-1251* then the error. The data is windows-1251 encoded, the print r.text is 100 percent causing the error

Comment: @GreenAsJade, the full traceback is there, it literally cannot be any other part of the code causing the error. Where else do you think it could be from?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham only if there is no more content in the OP's program.

Comment: @GreenAsJade, I have absolutely no doubt what is causing the error and that  the OP has provided the relevant code.

Comment: @GreenAsJade, there are a million dupes of any scenario it happens to be, I am waiting for an answer to the question I asked so I can close it with the correct one.

Comment: @GreenAsJade,   You have already stated the code does not error for you  so how do you think requests guessed the wrong encoding? Have a look at the headers the server sets and look at the charset in the source  inside the meta tags. requests also does not guess the encoding is ascii so where do you think the ascii error comes from, maybe the print?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  OK - thanks, will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content):

> Requests will automatically decode content from the server. Most
>   unicode charsets are seamlessly decoded.
>
> When you make a request, Requests makes educated guesses about the
>   encoding of the response based on the HTTP headers.

`requests.get().encoding` is telling you the encoding that was used to convert the bitstream from the server into the Unicode text that is in the response.

In your case it is correct: the headers in the response say that the character set is windows-1251

The error you are having is after that.   The python you are using is trying to encode the Unicode into ascii to print it, and failing.

You can say print `r.text.encode(r.encoding)` ... which is the same result as Padraic's suggestion in comments - that is `r.content`.

---

Note:
`requests.get().encoding` is an lvar: you can set it to what you want, if it guessed wrongly.